# LG G2 Wireless storage usage in Linux

Tags: android

LG G2 Wireless Storage lets you have access to your phone's files (Pictures, Music, vidoes...) wirelessly from your PC. Make sure both devices are connected to the same Wi-Fi network and then do as follows to start the connection.

Is there any method which can help me to use wireless storage in Linux Crunchbang?

http://androidwidgetcenter.com/android-tips/setup-wireless-storage-lg-g2/

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, is exactly the same as a SMB resource.

Comment: @Braiam well sorry I don't know what SMB means but I came across with this term while I was reading about wireless storage so you are probably right.